# SQL with @ and spaces

Tags: oracle, path, sqlplus

I have an sql batch file "My Test File.sql" that contains

```
@.\report\report1.sql;
```

If I drag this file into oracle, then it runs no problem.

The file is located in a folder called "All Reports"

So I want to create another sql batch file to call the above file

```
"@.\All Reports\My Test File.sql;"
```

But this gives me an identifier too long error.

Is there a way to call "My Test File.sql" using a relative path @

Comment: try `@".\All Reports\My Test File.sql"`

Comment: That read the "My Test File.sql" file, but now it is unable to read report1.sql

Comment: I will update the question.

Comment: This answered my original question. Thank you

Comment: Filenames which contain spaces are an abomination. It's bad enough when they're Word docs for requirements or whatever but those are written by BAs who don't know any better. There is absolutely no reason for executable files to contain spaces. Fixing the file name is the only one correct solution.